# Youtube GData 2 thousand most viewed

Tags: python, youtube, gdata

I want to catch the 1 thousand most viewed youtube videos through gdata youtube api.

However, only the first 84 are being returned.

If I use the following query, only 34 records are returned (plus the first 50).

Anyone knows what is wrong?

"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?start-index=1"
returns 25 records

"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?start-index=26"
returns 25 records

"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?start-index=51"
returns 25 records

"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?start-index=76"
returns 9 records

Comment: Hi Tim, I inserted the queries.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube will not provide this to you. They intentionally rate limit their feeds to prevent abuse.

Comment: According to the gdata documentation, the limit number of feeds is one thousand.